# Regex instance can not find more than one match even though it exists

Tags: c#, regex

I was using Regex and I wrote this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "this a string meant to test long space recognition      n       a";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z][\s]{4,}[a-z]$");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);
        if (matches.Count > 1)
            Console.WriteLine("yes");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
            Console.WriteLine("the number of matches is "+matches.Count);
        }
    }
```

In my opinion the Matches method should find both "n      n" and "n      a". Nevertheless, it only manages to find "n     n" and I just do not understand why is that..

Comment: The regex is consuming the second `n` in its first match.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` in your regular expression means, that the pattern must occur at the end of the line. If you want to find all the long spaces this simple expression suffices:

```
\s{4,}
```

If you really need to know whether the spaces are enclosed by a-z, you can search like this

```
(?<=[a-z])\s{4,}(?=[a-z])
```

This uses the pattern...

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

...and finds positions enclosed between a prefix and a suffix. The prefix and suffix are not part of the match, i.e. `match.Value` contains only the contiguous spaces. Therefore you don't get the *"n" is consumed* problem mentioned by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Yes (+1) -- look-around assertions are the key to this kind of problem because they don't "consume" characters as the engine runs through the string from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1) You're anchoring the match to the end of the string. So actually, the value that's matched is "n...a", not "n...n"

2) The middle "n" is consumed by the first match, so can't be part of the second match. If you change that "n" to "nx" (and remove the $) you'll see "n...n" and "x...a"

Short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "ignored a      bc       d";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z][\s]{4,}[a-z]");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
a      b
c       d
```

Answer (score 0):

`I just do not understand why is that..`

I think the 'why' it is consumed by the first match is to prevent regexes like `"\\w+s"`, designed to get every word that ends with an 's' from returning "ts", "ats" and "cats" when matched against "cats".

Comment: Matches can simply not overlap. After regex finds a match, it continues searching after that match. It's the same behavior as the Find (Ctrl/F) function in VS or MS Word or almost any other text editor.

Comment: @Oliver - Exactly, my answer was probably more suited as a comment on Jon's post. But I don't have the rep for that yet.

Answer (score -3):

The Regex machinery does *one* match, if you want more, you have to restart it youself after the first match.

Comment: Nope: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx

Comment: `regex.Matches` yields all the matches.